# jsoup: differnt result after updating from 1.7.3 to 1.8.1, how to avoid this?

Tags: java, jsoup

After updating from jsoup 1.7.3 to 1.8.1 I get differnt results.
In 1.7.3 the title attribute was returned escaped, same as the input, in 1.8.1 the br is converted into a tag.
Is there a way I can avoid this behaviour?

```
String content = "<a href=\"javascript:openObj('Classifier_UUID')\" title=\"Test&lt;br&gt;Test\">Test<br>Test</a>";
Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(content);
document.outputSettings().charset(Charset.forName("ASCII")); //$NON-NLS-1$
System.out.println(document.body().html());
```

Result:

```
// 1.7.3 <a href="javascript:openObj('Classifier_UUID')" title="Test&lt;br&gt;Test">Test<br />Test</a>
// 1.8.1 <a href="javascript:openObj('Classifier_UUID')" title="Test<br>Test">Test<br>Test</a>
```

Comment: Escape it? Seems that jsoup is no longer making that decision for you.

Comment: I actually use this code to escape HTML, which works great. Except for this new behaviour.

Comment: I don't see your escape code.  If this was a side-effect of the `parseBodyFragment` call, clearly you can't rely on it anymore.

Comment: The jsoup parsing is the escape code, having the following input 
 "…‘’‚“”„•‰€™äöüèéàÄÖÜÀÉÈ\"&°"
 will return "&#x2026;&#x2018;&#x2019;&#x201a;&#x201c;&#x201d;&#x201e;&#x2022;&#x2030;&#x20ac;&#x2122;&auml;&ouml;&uuml;&egrave;&eacute;&agrave;&Auml;&Ouml;&Uuml;&Agrave;&Eacute;&Egrave;\"&amp;&deg;"

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late but could help some others.

I upgraded from jsoup *1.7.2* to *1.11.3* and had the same behaviour that the escaping is not implicit anymore.

The following code did the trick for me:

```
String cleanText = Jsoup.clean(s, Whitelist.none());
//& and <,> are escaped from .clean call so we have to unescape them
String cleanUnencodedText = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(cleanText);
String cleanEncodedText = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3(cleanUnencodedText);
```

As you can see i first had to unescape the `cleanedText` because `& < <` are escaped by `Jsoup.Clean` call.

You can use `unescapeHtml4` and `escapeHtml4` instead of the Html 3 versions. I had to support the old html version cause
e.g Html 4 escapes `€` through `&euro;`