# How to parse xhtml with jsoup without changing Html or parsing Html entities

Tags: java, html, xhtml, jsoup

I am using jsoup parser to manipulate  xhtml file.
My file contains below tag as I/P

```html
<param name="video_title" value="&lt;p&gt;Renewable Energy&lt;/p&gt;" />
```

I passed this tag to jsoup parser using object html as below

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document blogContentDocument = Jsoup.parse(html, "", Parser.xmlParser());
org.jsoup.select.Elements all_elements = blogContentDocument.select("*");
```

and after returning all_elements my o/p be like

```html
<param name="video_title" value="<p>Renewable Energy</p>" />
```

Expected o/p :

```html
<param name="video_title" value="&lt;p&gt;Renewable Energy&lt;/p&gt;" />
```

can anyone suggest me how i can prevent jsoup parser from changing html encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the jsoup version this will work:

```
Document document = ...;
document.outputSettings().charset(Charset.forName("ASCII")); //$NON-NLS-1$
System.out.println(document.body().html());
```

A solution might be to downgrade to a Jsoup version below 1.8.x. The escape behavior changed from 1.7.x to 1.8.x.

Here an example:

- 1.7.3 `<a href="#" title="Test&lt;br&gt;Test">Test<br />Test</a>`
- 1.8.1 `<a href="#" title="Test<br>Test">Test<br>Test</a>`

There is some more information on this topic here:
[jsoup: differnt result after updating from 1.7.3 to 1.8.1, how to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28881191/jsoup-differnt-result-after-updating-from-1-7-3-to-1-8-1-how-to-avoid-this)

Another solution could be, the apache commons **[StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)**. 
Escape the `value` after parsing and placing the escaped value back into the element attribute.

```
org.jsoup.select.Elements all_elements = blogContentDocument.select("*");
for (Element element : all_elements) {
    String escaped = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(element.attr("value"));
    element.attr("value", escaped);
    System.out.println(element);
}

// check if the content is changed in the document
System.out.println(blogContentDocument.html());
```